# Setting up online payments for website

Tags: php, payment

I am a web designer but haven't set up online payments before. I'm using a linux server with php and MySQL. I have a new contract to set up a very simple website where people can buy one of three different products (very basic). I want them to be able to pay using credit/debit cards. My question is can anyone point me to a good resource page for setting this up?

I don't think it is worth me installing an open source solution such as Opencart, Zencart or Presta because there are only three products to choose from and users won't need to register, just buy it online. so I am thinking the best way is to hand code it, however I'm sure it's been done many times before and there must be a good resource for this.  I know I'll have to use a secure certificate and also use a gateway to handle the payments, I just need the information on how to do this. If anyone can point me in the right direction or offer any advice on going about setting it up I would appreciate it.

Comment: My suggestion would be for you to use either paypal or google checkout

Comment: can only second @JohnP. outsource as many of those payment issues as you can. this isn't just code, it's also about handling and storing (or not) sensible data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

paypal web payments standard is one of the cheapest ways to get setup, the paypal website can generate all the code you need to paste into your website to facilitate the process.

downsides. higher merchant fee (at time of writing i think it is about 3.4% + a per transaction fee)

if you are selling high price items or high volumes you can save money by setting up a merchant account direct with your bank and getting a payment processor to handle the transactions. most of them have an option for a hosted payment page. (eg they handle all the secure part of the transaction, and fire back a message to your site to confirm the process is successful)

shop around first, and try their demo sites, because some of the hosted payments pages are (in typical bank style) very very user unfriendly

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I think I will be going for a hosted payment page through a bank with a merchant account. This seems like the easiest option to me.

Comment: Pay with Creditcards through facebook! https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/>

Answer (score 5):

Payments authorization is not something that you do by yourself. What you can do is to open a merchant account with a bank or to use an API from Paypal, Google checkout, Authorize.net or others. Opencart, Magento or Presta will act as intermediaries and they have modules that allow sending the data to the entity that can check and charge the credit card. That entity will send you back a message that the transaction succeeded or not. This way the clients are protected and you dont have to develop your (potentialy unsecure) solution.

If you are a web designer I would recommend you to concentrate on design and not to complicate your life with an implementation that can be complicated and potentially risky for the client. Just collaborate with a programmer who has experience in this.

Comment: Thanks Elzo for your helpful answer. As I said below I'll use a hosted payment solution. I want to learn about online payments myself as it will be useful for future projects. Also this is a small budget site so I don't think I can afford to bring in a programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you are a web designer you are still able to do the online payments for your website.

At first, there are some easy ways to handle payment, like paypal website stardard. If you are using third party cart, there are plenty of online payment integration, you don't need to worry about API as long as you're not developing it by yourself; it would be a hell of a headache.

Third party integration is very helpful and very understandable, they will give you the module and instructions for the payment integration of your site. Again, even if you are a web designer, you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

For selling only one of three different products you may want to try a Buy Now button or a simple shopping cart. You would still need an online payment processor like PayPal or Google Checkout to comply with all the credit card government regulations (e.g. PCI compliance).

For PHP shopping cart integration examples using Goolge Checkout you may find this sample code useful:

http://code.google.com/p/google-checkout-php-sample-code/

Hope this helps...